# How can I get a back button link to return to ORIGINAL search page?

Tags: javascript, java, hyperlink, browser-history, back

How can I get a "Back to Search Page" hyperlink to return users to the original Search tab after they have viewed results on other pages?  Here is the setup within which I am working with.

- Search 1, Search 2, Search 3 all share a Search Results Page. (I cannot change this)
- There is a Back to Search Page link on the Search Results Page.
- When users view an item on Search Results Page, it takes them to View Page.
- When they return from View Page back to Search Results Page, the "Back to Search Page" link returns them to the View Page link (bc the function currently is history.back)

So is there a way for that "Back to Search Page" link to return the user to the first, original Search page? I am thinking I should be able to store the Operation Code of the original search page but am not sure how to save it and then call back to it within the function without it being overwritten by whatever other page the user views before returning to that link. I just cannot get my mind to wrap around how to do this, if it is even a valid solution.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**How the Back to Search Results link is currently displayed in the .jsp:**

```
 <TD><A HREF='javascript:backToSearchView();'><B>Back_To_Search_Page</B></A></TD>
```

**The function currently in .js:**

```
//4.19 BACK TO SEARCH PAGE FROM TRANS VIEW
function backToSearchView(){
    history.back();
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call your result search page, you could add a parameter to remember which search page called it.

On the search page :

```
window.location.href = './result-page.html?caller=Search1'
```

And in your result page you store that value like so :

```
var url = new URL(document.URL);
var caller = url.searchParams.get("caller"); // Value = Search1

[...]
// On the click of the "Go Back" button
if (caller == "Search1"){
   window.location.href = "./search1.html"
}
else if(caller == "Search2"){
   window.location.href = "./search2.html"
}
else{
   window.location.href = "./search3.html"
}
```

Comment: I would then call for "caller" in the function? ```javascript:backToSearchView("caller")```?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use **local storage** to save original params or whole link and then read it to get user back to original search page.

This will work even if the page is changed when viewing results or reloaded. (anything else stored as a normal variable in javascript will be cleared when page changes or is reloaded. )

Before going to search result in original search page **store** needed information like this:

```js
localStorage.setItem("returnURL",window.location.href);
//or params
localStorage.setItem("param1","param1Value");
```

Then **read local storage** to return user to its original search state when clicking on return button:

```js
url = localStorage.getItem("returnURL");
//or params
param1 = localStorage.getItem("param1");
```